# php session is lost on redirect

Tags: php, session

I am trying to use secure sessions here. This is a piece of code i adopted while researching.
Unfortunately the session does not load when the headers are redirected.
Could someone please explain what is happening and point me in the right direction.

Here's the code

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
    {
        $dir_path = ini_get("session.save_path") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . _SESSION_DIR;
        if(!is_dir($dir_path)) mkdir($dir_path);

        if( ini_get('session.use_trans_sid') == true) {
            ini_set('url_rewriter.tags' , '');
            ini_set('session.use_trans_sid' , false);
        }

        $lifetime = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1;
        //$lifetime = 60;
        ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime' , $lifetime);
        ini_set('session.gc_divisor' , '1');
        ini_set('session.gc_probability' , '1');
        ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime' , '0');
        ini_set('session.save_path', $dir_path);
        session_name(_SESSION_NAME);
        session_start();
```

Comment: Check the value of `session_id()` in each page. if it changes, then you're losing the session cookie and getting a new/fresh/empty session each time. Probably due to a bad cookie_path setting, or a cookie setting problem in your client.

Comment: Yes currently working on local machine using xampp and YES , it does change session_id each time. The cookie is created at the desired path , i.e , xampp/tmp/cookie_name. Before redirecting the session works just fine. Really want to know , what feel like knowing what am i missing here

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to retrieve sessions that were created on a previous page, You have to make sure that you used a `session_write_close()` after you wrote your sessions. Then in order to use them on subsequent pages you have to call `session_start()` **BEFORE** you can use them. You can see more on [sessions here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php)

Comment: Wrong. PHP automatically closes/saves session data when the script terminates. session_write_close() is only necessary for long-running scripts and you need to release the lock that is otherwise held on the session file. That's the whole point of session_start(): one call (before any output) and PHP does the rest for you. You don't have to do anythign else to "preserve" session data, as long as the session cookie settings are working correctly.

Comment: You are correct in that the session at the end of script, But I read and experienced sessions not saving when a redirect occurs before a `session_write_close()`. This is also mentioned in a comment on php.net [here](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php#37644). I'm not saying that you are wrong @MarcB but i thought given the situation this would solve the problem.